# gdata python analytics metrics and dimensions error

Tags: python, gdata-api

I am using the gdata module in python, when using this query I get an 'Illegal combination of dimensions and metrics' error. I have looked at documentation but not found the reason.

```
data_query = gdata.analytics.client.DataFeedQuery({
        'ids': tid,
        'start-date': '2010-04-20',
        'end-date': '2010-04-21',
        'dimensions': 'ga:date,ga:hour,ga:medium,ga:source,ga:keyword',
        'metrics': 'ga:visits',
        'sort': 'ga:date,ga:hour',
        'filters': 'ga:exitPagePath=@/blabla', 
        'max-results': '10000'})
```

Dirk

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [data explorer](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html) to manually construct the uri first.